# Were schools for disabled tolerated by Nazi Germany?

Tags: nazi-germany

I am trying to find out if schools for disabled children were permitted to exist in Nazi Germany. In particular I am  looking for a source of anecdotal testimony by survivors of the t4 programme of euthanasia.

Comment: Blind children were even allowed to joint the [HJ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HJ-Bann_B) as long as they were not deemed mentally disabled as well. Generally speaking, the Nazis were careful how much they could antagonize the German relatives of their victims, cf the [Rosenstrasse protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstrasse_protest).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: I don't have the time to do it justice, but a summary of this https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonderp%C3%A4dagogik_im_Nationalsozialismus would answer the question pretty well. If someone else reads german, go for it.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. Thank heavens for google translate. Many thanks again.